# How does ./ and ../ actually work? I have a perculiar case

Tags: node.js

I have a peculiar case that I can't figure out. First, let's say I have a file system such as follows.

```
webdev/
├── app.js
├── comment.html
├── controller/
│   └── controller.js
└── model/
    └── model.js
```

In `app.js`:

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const commentHtml = fs.readFileSync(`./comment.html`,"utf-8");
console.log(commentHtml);
```

So of course this works right? `./` means relative path. It also works if I do:

```
const commentHtml = fs.readFileSync(`comment.html`,"utf-8");
```

ok that's also not weird. Now, in `controller.js`:

```js
const commentHtml = fs.readFileSync(`./comment.html`,"utf-8");
const model = require("./../model/model.js");
```

these both work. first of all, for the `readFileSync("./comment.html")` should mean that the file sits in `controller/` but it sits in `webdev/`. Yet it still works.

Meanwhile, if I use `require("./model/model.js")` it would give me an error. According to how `./` and `../` works, `require("./model/model.js")` is wrong. So why does `readFileSync("./comment.html")` work? Btw I did `console.log` on it and it definitely read it both times, it's not a case of errors not showing.

Comment: Are you sure there is no `comment.html` in `controller/`?

Comment: No, I am sure because I've tested it out extensively and moved files around a lot to test. Basically it comes down to this. given /projects/files1.js and projects/folder/files2.js. Running these two commands in files2.js works - readFileSync("./files2.js") and require("./../files2.js") . Giving it any other path will break it. It looks like filesync starts out in parent directory and require starts out in the relative directory. I just can't find anywhere that says so online. That's what happens in testing though.

Answer (score 0):

You can import files using the relative path or the absolute path.

`./` => is used to import a file under the same folder that you are in.
`../` => is used to import a file in a parent directory.

let's have an example:

consider I have three files
First one => `C: Documents/projects/folder1/file1.js`.
Second one => `C: Documents/projects/folder1/file2.js`.
Third one => `C: Documents/projects/folder2/file3.js`

and I want to import `file3` and `file2` in `file1`
It would be like this

```js
// in file1.js
const file2 = fs.readFileSync(`./file2.js`,"utf-8"); // as it is in the same directory
const file3 = fs.readFileSync(`../folder2/file3.js`,"utf-8"); // as it is in a parent directory
```

Comment: The peculiar situation I'm speaking about contradicts what you said. Regarding the ./, in my situation, the files2.js is sitting in /projects/ and not in /folders1/. Yet it can still be read when file1.js is sitting in /folders1/. That is the case for fs.readFileSync but it's not true for require("path").  Below I'll show the two paths that work if file2.js sits in /projects

```
readFileSync("./files2.js"
require("./../files2.js")

```
meanwhile, if i put readFileSync("./../files2.js" - it will not work. so it looks like filesync starts out in parents directory, require is relative

Answer (score 0):

I actually discovered the reason so I'll answer it here to help others. `./` when using `require()` means the location of the file it is sitting in. with `fs` functions, it is where your current terminal directory is.